# Add multiple sip registrars to one phone

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server

I'd like to integrate some phone status information into our crm system (calling, on the hook, busy etc). I would prefer not to build and maintain a fully functioning SIP server because i only need very basic information. Also, our VOIP provider already maintains a fully functioning SIP server, and they are way better at it. Basically, I would my crm sever to be kept up to date on anything the phone does? Would it be possible for our crm server to receive any SIP messages the phones send to our VOIP provider.

1. Can I tell a sip phone to do that?
2. Is such a feature supported by many phones?
3. Am i looking at this in the wrong way? I'm completely new to SIP and phone integration so there is a good chance there is an easier or better way to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use phone feature called Action URL. It is generating HTTP GET requests on events like on hook / off hook, these request can be used to pass events to CRM.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm not sure this will work for me since i don't think it is supported by all phone types. For now i'll keep your idea as my back up plan. If i can't get it to work with SIP subscribe messages..

Comment: Does your operator supports BLF? You might register another softphone, subscribe to status of your other extensions and pass events to CRM. I'm developing one that might be suitable: tSIP - "on BLF change" Lua script can launch some command line tool like http client passing phone number and state CRM.

Comment: That is a really cool idea! That's definitely a direction that i will have to look into. Thank you for your insights!